# Bean-Validation not working under JSF2.2 (Majorra 2.2.5)

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, jsf-2.2

after upgrading from Majorra 2.1.27 to 2.2.5 my Bean-Validation stopped working. Simple example:

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel for="tf_name" />
    <h:inputText id="tf_name" value="#{test.testEntity.name}" />
    <h:message for="tf_name" />
    <br />
    <h:commandButton value="save" action="#{test.cantTouchThis}"/>
</h:form>
```

The field "name" on my TestEntity is annotated with @NotNull (and i have set `INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` to true in web.xml +`org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO` to false for my tomcat).

If i use Majorra 2.1.27 (i use maven btw.) everything works fine. But if i switch to 2.2.5 my Method cantTouchThis() is called, even when i leave the fields empty. I also tried with other validators, none of them seem to work. Validation is skipped completely.

any ideas?

Comment: process="@form" and update="@form" are not attributes belonging to h:commandButton. Try with MyFaces, sometimes what doesn't work with one implementation works with the other. It looks like a bug in Mojarra, but who knows, the example also looks incorrect to me.

Comment: You are right, that was some crap due to to switch PrimeFaces (p:) components to JSF2 (h:) components for this example. I reworked the example now, and removed one of the two fields. Should be correct now. Still: Validation is skipped on 2.2.5 only. Will try MyFaces just for completeness, though i experienced much better performance with majorra (which seems odd, given that "word on the street" seems to say different)

Comment: Tried it now. Works fine on MyFaces 2.1.14 and 2.2.0. So it's working everywhere except Majorra 2.2.5... Maybe really a bug in the implementation..

Comment: Ok, good to know that. Maybe you should report it to Majorra issue tracker. In term of performance the evidence suggest MyFaces is really good, no doubt about that. See [Understanding JSF 2.0 Performance – Part 3](http://content.jsfcentral.com/c/journal/view_article_content?cmd=view&groupId=35702&articleId=73398&version=1.8#.UwQVRM7dDQ8) for more details. The good part of this comparison is that it also provide the source code, so you can try it for yourself. Please use the latest versions of MyFaces, which are considered more stable and have fewer bugs, thanks to the community feedback.

Comment: Issue created: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3183

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As tipped by lu4242 this was a bug in Mojarra. The bug emerged in version 2.2.3 and is fixed with 2.2.7 (which at the time of writing this is not officially released).

See [JAVASERVERFACES-3183](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/3187) for more details.